# References - Why do the following two programs produce different output?

Tags: c++, reference, static, output

I recently read about references in C++. I am aware of basic properties of references but I am still not able to figure out why following two programs produce different output.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int &fun()
{
    static int x = 10;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout << fun();
    return 0;
}
```

This program prints `30` as output. As per my understanding, the function `fun()` returns a reference to memory location occupied by `x` which is then assigned a value of `30` and in the second call of `fun()` the assignment statement is ignored. 
Now consider this program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int &fun()
{
    int x = 10;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout << fun();
    return 0;
}
```

This program produces the output as `10`. Is it because, after the first call, `x` is assigned `30`, and after second call it is again overwritten to `10` because it is a local variable? Am I wrong anywhere? Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, `fun()` returns a reference to the same variable no matter how many times you call it.

In the second case, `fun()` returns a dangling reference to a different variable on every call. The reference is not valid after the function returns.

When you use

```
fun() = 30;
```

in the second case, you are setting the value of a variable that is not valid any longer. In theory, that is undefined behavior.

When you call `fun()` the second time in the second case, the variable `x` is set to `10`. That is independent of the first call to the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to what has been said. The reason behind the first case's behavior is because it is a `static` variable, which has a static duration. Static duration means that the object or variable is allocated when the program starts and is deallocated when the program ends.

This means that once `x` in the first case has been initialized the first time with `10`, the next function call will ignore `static int x = 10;` because `x` cannot be instantiated again, as it has already been allocated, and will simply proceed to `return x;`, which will be the same `x` that was assigned `30` in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your understanding is right, except for in 2nd case, you're processing a dangled reference of the local variable has been invalid, which is undefined behaviour, means anything is possible. What you said is just one of the possibility, it also could result in others, such as getting a random number, program crash, etc.